# What does the new money tree yield upon removal?

Tags: clash-of-clans

After the winter update, I started noticing what look like golden money trees show up in my main Clash of Clans base. What do those yield upon removing them from your base?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new obstacle is called the fortune tree, and upon removal, the tree grants 75000 gold coins.